# Show that all solutions of $y'= \frac{xy+1}{x^2+1}$ are of the form $y=x+C\sqrt {1+x^2}$ without solving the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think I'm supposed to use the existence and uniqueness theorem, but I'm not sure how. (because we're not allowed to actually solve the ODE)

Also, is it ok if I just differentiate y and plug it in the ODE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to show that **ALL** the solutions of the given differential equation are of the given form, which means that plugging it in is not enough.

You're given a differential problem of the form :

$$y'=f(x,y)$$

In such cases, a solution exists if $f(x,y)$ is either continuous everywhere, or around a given initial value.

In your case, the function at the RHS is :

$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy+1}{x^2+1}$$

It's obvious that $f$ is continuous $\forall \space (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, thus a solution to the differential equation exists.

To show that the solution is unique, you have to show that the function $f(x,y)$ is ***Lipschitz*** or in other words, it's derivative with respect to $y$ is bounded.

Truly then :

$$|f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)|=\bigg|\frac{xy_2+1}{x^2+1} - \frac{xy_1+1}{x^2+1}\bigg|= \bigg|\frac{x(y_2-y_1)}{x^2+1} \bigg|=\bigg|\frac{x}{x^2+1} \bigg||y_2-y_1|$$

The function :

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$

is bounded and independent of $y_1,y_2$, thus there exists one **unique** solution to the given differential equation problem.

Now, after showing that is unique, if plugging it in works, then **all** the solutions of the given differential problem are of the given form.

Answer (score 2):

A general idea that might work (but I did not try): if $y$ is a solution, define $v$ by setting $y(x)-x=v(x) \sqrt{1+x^2}$. Now try to prove that $v$ must be constant, by using the equation for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is supposed to be as follows:

Let $y$ be a solution to the ODE. Define a new function $g(x)= \frac{y-x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

We'll prove that $g'(x)=0$ for all x, this would mean that $g(x)$ is constant.

From the previous equation we can see that $y= x+g(x)\sqrt{1+x^2}$, and so:

$y'=1+g'(x)\sqrt{1+x^2}+\frac{xg(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

$g'(x)\sqrt{1+x^2}=y'-1-\frac{xg(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=y'-\frac{xy+1}{1+x^2}=0$

$g'(x)=0$